# If $G/[G,G]=0$, does that imply that $G=0$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group such that $G/[G,G]$ is trivial, where $[G,G]$ is the commutator subgroup of $G$. Does this necessarily imply that $G$ is trivial? In other words, does $[G,G]$ have to be a proper subgroup of $G$ if $G$ is non-trivial?

Comment: That $\;0\;$ looks pretty weird. I suppose you meant what if $\;G/G'\;$ is trivial. What must be then deduced is that $\;G=G'\;$ , meaning: $\;G\;$ is perfect.

Comment: @DonAntonio- I've made the edits

Answer (score 4):

Not at all. For example, $\;A_5/[A_5,A_5]=1\;$ since $\;[A_5,A_5]=A_5\;$ is a perfect group.

In fact, any non-abelian *simple* group must be perfect, and the above one is the smallest-order such example.

Comment: Ah. I didn't know about perfect groups. Thanks!